# parsing nested json file spark/pyspark

Tags: json, apache-spark

I am having a challenge with parsing a nested json file using spark:

a simple json one level file is working fine:

```
myJson = '{"Name":"something","Url":"https://stackoverflow.com","Author":"jangcy","BlogEntries":100,"Caller":"jangcy"}'
df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([myJson]))
df.show()
+------+-----------+------+---------+--------------------+
|Author|BlogEntries|Caller|     Name|                 Url|
+------+-----------+------+---------+--------------------+
|jangcy|        100|jangcy|something|https://stackover...|
+------+-----------+------+---------+--------------------+
```

But when i try to do the same with a more complex nested json like below I am not getting the data presented right & get _corrupt_record message..

```
 file_name =[
 ('{"user":10, "ips" : ["170.168.192.101", "171.168.192.103", "171.168.192.96", 
 "191.168.192.99"]}',), ('{"user":21, "ips" : ["131.168.192.10", "181.168.192.105", 
 "191.168.192.103", "191.168.192.107"]}',),
 ('{"user":13, "ips" : ["191.168.192.105", "191.168.192.101", "191.168.192.105", 
 "191.168.192.107"]}',),('{"user":42, "ips" : ["191.168.192.96", "191.168.192.100", 
 "191.168.192.107", "191.168.192.101"]}',),
 ('{"user":15, "ips" : ["191.168.192.99", "191.168.192.99", "191.168.192.102", 
 "191.168.192.99"]}',),('{"user":6, "ips" : ["191.168.192.99", "191.168.192.99", 
 "191.168.192.100", "191.168.192.96"]}',),]
```

any suggestion on how to parse such json file? I want to pull the ips out so I can do a count on each occurrence

Answer (score 0):

You either need to remove `'` quotation marks from your `dictionary` or read them as `string` `dictionary`. Something like below -

```
file_name =[
 ({"user":10, "ips" : ["170.168.192.101", "171.168.192.103", "171.168.192.96", 
 "191.168.192.99"]},), ({"user":21, "ips" : ["131.168.192.10", "181.168.192.105", 
 "191.168.192.103", "191.168.192.107"]},),
 ({"user":13, "ips" : ["191.168.192.105", "191.168.192.101", "191.168.192.105", 
 "191.168.192.107"]},),({"user":42, "ips" : ["191.168.192.96", "191.168.192.100", 
 "191.168.192.107", "191.168.192.101"]},),
 ({"user":15, "ips" : ["191.168.192.99", "191.168.192.99", "191.168.192.102", 
 "191.168.192.99"]},),({"user":6, "ips" : ["191.168.192.99", "191.168.192.99", 
 "191.168.192.100", "191.168.192.96"]},)]
```

Or

```
file_name =[
 ("""{"user":10, "ips" : ["170.168.192.101", "171.168.192.103", "171.168.192.96", 
 "191.168.192.99"]}""",), ("""{"user":21, "ips" : ["131.168.192.10", "181.168.192.105", 
 "191.168.192.103", "191.168.192.107"]}""",),
 ("""{"user":13, "ips" : ["191.168.192.105", "191.168.192.101", "191.168.192.105", 
 "191.168.192.107"]}""",),("""{"user":42, "ips" : ["191.168.192.96", "191.168.192.100", 
 "191.168.192.107", "191.168.192.101"]}""",),
 ("""{"user":15, "ips" : ["191.168.192.99", "191.168.192.99", "191.168.192.102", 
 "191.168.192.99"]}""",),("""{"user":6, "ips" : ["191.168.192.99", "191.168.192.99", 
 "191.168.192.100", "191.168.192.96"]}""",)]
```

From here on, its pretty much straight forward flatten the rows and explode your column `ips` as -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize(file_name).flatMap(lambda x: x))
                     
df.withColumn("exploded_ips", explode(col('ips'))).limit(5).show(truncate=False)

+-------------------------------------------------------------------+----+---------------+
|ips                                                                |user|exploded_ips   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+----+---------------+
|[170.168.192.101, 171.168.192.103, 171.168.192.96, 191.168.192.99] |10  |170.168.192.101|
|[170.168.192.101, 171.168.192.103, 171.168.192.96, 191.168.192.99] |10  |171.168.192.103|
|[170.168.192.101, 171.168.192.103, 171.168.192.96, 191.168.192.99] |10  |171.168.192.96 |
|[170.168.192.101, 171.168.192.103, 171.168.192.96, 191.168.192.99] |10  |191.168.192.99 |
|[131.168.192.10, 181.168.192.105, 191.168.192.103, 191.168.192.107]|21  |131.168.192.10 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+----+---------------+
```